# cordova push and local notification conflict

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, push-notification

I created a mobile App (Ionic + Cordova). Installed [Cordova Push Notifications](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), [Cordova Local-Notification Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) But when I get a push notification or off the screen I lose all my local notifications. And if check them by isScheduled function I get TRUE. If I remove a push notification code

```
var config = null;
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            config = {
                "senderID": "111111111111" // REPLACE THIS WITH YOURS FROM GCM CONSOLE - also in the project URL like: https://console.developers.google.com/project/434205989073
                //"ecb": "window.onNotificationGCM"
            }
        } else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            config = {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true"
            }
        }

        $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {
            // ** NOTE: Android regid result comes back in the pushNotificationReceived, only iOS returned here
            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
                $rootScope.regId = result;
                scheduleNotifications.storeDeviceToken("ios");
            }
        }, function(err) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Register error " + err);
        });
```

it works ok. What can be wrong with this?

Comment: Any update on this?  I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution - just add  "clearNotifications": false to push notification init

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
        "senderID": "114273210157",
        "clearNotifications": false
       },
       "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have it good because I can't even run them together.

```
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support
    /v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfo
    VersionImpl;
```

Local Notification is installing android.support.v4 as a dependency which conflicts with the rest of Ionic.

EDIT: fixed by nuking the v4.jar file under platforms/android/libs.

Comment: Hi tacobot, I removed android-support-v4.jar from  platforms/android/libs and it fixed UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: but I still have problem - when I get a push notification or off the screen I lose all my local notifications. Have you had this issue or both notification work normal?

Comment: @VolodymyrLysytsia Any update? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @SaribanD'Cl no still the same( I created clear build with only two these plugins but got the same issue.